# RadcomboBoxes cascading with Load on demand with WCF

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, telerik

Is it possible to use Load on Demand with WCF service for Cascading RadComboBox? Please let me know if there are any examples. I didn't see any demo on Telerik website.

Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may combine following examples:

1. Load on demand: https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/loadondemand/wcf/defaultcs.aspx
2. Related combo boxes: https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/multiplecomboboxes/defaultcs.aspx
3. Overview: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combo_loadondemandoverview.html